# Can we use Backup-Sqldatabase cmdlet in powershell to generate stripped backup?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I could successfully backup database using Backup-Sqldatabase cmdlet to one .bak file. However, I was want to generate stripped backup files for the database. Is this possible using the cmdlet?

Comment: Are you sure striped backups are what you really need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt683378.aspx) has a parameter `-backupFile` that accetps an array of file names. At least with the `-Script` parameter the emitted TSQL looks sensible, so it ought to work. Like so,

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> Backup-SqlDatabase -Script -ServerInstance ".\sqli001" -Database TestDB -BackupFile @("c:\temp\1.bak", "c:\temp\2.bak")

BACKUP DATABASE [TestDB] TO  DISK = N'c:\temp\1.bak',  DISK = N'c:\temp\2.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NOSKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only generate the code to take backup.

Use the below PowerShell script to execute the backup and I have provided a way to pass the dynamic value to the backup file path as well shown below.

```
 $path = 'D:\BackupFolder\TestDB.Bak,E:\BackupFolder\TestDB.Bak'

 $QUERY = Backup-SqlDatabase -Script -ServerInstance ServerName  -Database TestDB -BackupFile @($path.split(','))

 invoke-sqlcmd -query "$QUERY" -ServerInstance "SQLInstanceName"
```